# How to integrate Swagger in Lumen/Laravel for REST API?

Tags: laravel-5.4, lumen

I have built some REST API in Lumen micro framework and it's working fine. Now I want to integrate Swagger into it so the API will be well documented on future use. Has anyone done this?

Comment: This might be of interest: https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume

Comment: @KimberlyW: i have integrate this but how to use it?

Comment: You need to add swagger comments as shown in the link below and follow the documentation from SwaggerLume for generating the actual Swagger HTML pages. 
https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php

Comment: @AnandPandey I listed all endpoints created by Lumen and found Swagger UI webpage on `/api/documentation` path and the Swagger json on `/docs` path. I didn't find anything in the docs though.

Comment: This article is helpful for every beginner https://www.phparticles.com/laravel/how-to-use-darkaonline-l5-swagger-in-laravel/

Comment: I used: **composer require "darkaonline/swagger-lume:8.*"** for my Lumen app on PHP8.

Answer (score 18):

Steps to follow for **Laravel Lumen 5.7** with swagger using **OpenApi 3.0** specs (this governs the way you write annotations so that swagger documentation is generated)

The steps were written a while ago but they still work with **Laravel Lumen 6.X, 7.X and 8.X**

I reached this adjusting on @black-mamba answer in order to make it work.

**1. Install swagger-lume dependency (which also installs swagger)**

```
composer require "darkaonline/swagger-lume:5.6.*"
```

**2. Edit `bootstrap/app.php` file**

> make sure `$app->withFacades();` is NOT commented (around line 26)
>
> in *Create The Application* section add the following before *Register Container Bindings* section
>
> ```
> $app->configure('swagger-lume');
> ```
>
> in *Register Service Providers* section add
>
> ```
> $app->register(\SwaggerLume\ServiceProvider::class);
> ```

**3. Publish configuration file for swagger-lume**

```
php artisan swagger-lume:publish
```

**4. Add annotations to your code**

For example in your `app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php` you could have the general part of the documentation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @OA\Info(
     *   title="Example API",
     *   version="1.0",
     *   @OA\Contact(
     *     email="support@example.com",
     *     name="Support Team"
     *   )
     * )
     */
}
```

And inside each of your controllers you should have the appropriate annotations above each public method

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *     path="/sample/{category}/things",
     *     operationId="/sample/category/things",
     *     tags={"yourtag"},
     *     @OA\Parameter(
     *         name="category",
     *         in="path",
     *         description="The category parameter in path",
     *         required=true,
     *         @OA\Schema(type="string")
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Parameter(
     *         name="criteria",
     *         in="query",
     *         description="Some optional other parameter",
     *         required=false,
     *         @OA\Schema(type="string")
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response="200",
     *         description="Returns some sample category things",
     *         @OA\JsonContent()
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response="400",
     *         description="Error: Bad request. When required parameters were not supplied.",
     *     ),
     * )
     */
    public function getThings(Request $request, $category)
    {
        $criteria= $request->input("criteria");
        if (! isset($category)) {
            return response()->json(null, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        
        // ...
        
        return response()->json(["thing1", "thing2"], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

**5. Generate swagger documentation**

```
php artisan swagger-lume:generate
```

Run this each time you update the documentation

---

see:

- https://zircote.github.io/swagger-php/
- https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume
- https://swagger.io/specification/

Comment: is there any way to make it auto generate annotaions ??? like what we have in .net core and django which u dont need to use annotations

Comment: @Farshad yes, in config/swagger-lume.php "SWAGGER_GENERATE_ALWAYS" and give it the value 'true' like this example 'generate_always' => env('SWAGGER_GENERATE_ALWAYS', true),

Comment: And finally access the swagger json locally use `[yourlocalhost]/docs`, and for ui locally use `[yourlocalhost]/api/documentation`. In case your UI missing assets, check this link [link](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume/issues/69).

Answer (score 11):

I had really hard time in learning how to use it. Here I'm going to share some of the things I did to get it working

[Use this wrapper](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume)

Run this command in your terminal:

```
composer require "darkaonline/swagger-lume:5.5.*"
```

Or older version from the repo linked if this doesn't work for you

Then from the repo follow these steps:

> Open your bootstrap/app.php file and:
>   uncomment this line (around line 26) in Create The Application
>   section:
>
> ```
>  $app->withFacades(); add this line before Register Container Bindings section:
>
>  $app->configure('swagger-lume'); add this line in Register Service Providers section:
>
> $app->register(\SwaggerLume\ServiceProvider::class);
> ```

Then you'll need to use annotations for your project instead of YAML or JSON
[For more](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/annotations)
Create a `Annotation.php` file in your app folder add the following a sample

```
/**
 * @SWG\Swagger(
 *     basePath="/",
 *     schemes={"http"},
 *     @SWG\Info(
 *         version="1.0.0",
 *         title="HAVE MY BOOKS",
 *         @SWG\Contact(
 *             email="example@test.com"
 *         ),
 *     )
 * )
 */
/**
* @SWG\Get(
 *   path="/",
 *   summary="Version",
 *   @SWG\Response(
 *     response=200,
 *     description="Working"
 *   ),
 *   @SWG\Response(
 *     response="default",
 *     description="an ""unexpected"" error"
 *   )
 * )
 */
```

Then run

```
php artisan swagger-lume:publish
```

Then run

```
php artisan swagger-lume:generate
```

This generates JSON which can be accessed from your localhost:8000 or whichever port you are serving your LUMEN service

> Note: after creating an issue in the repo I found that to access you'll need to serve or run using

```
php -S localhost:8000 public/index.php
```

Because of some PHP routing issue with `php -S localhost:8000 public`