# Lumen and Swagger integration

Tags: php, api, swagger, lumen

I have integrated swagger in lumen framework but for some reason swagger do not scan my project for annotations

I use **darkaonline/swagger-lumen: ~2.0** 
and   **laravel/lumen-framework: 5.4.***

Swagg that i get is from here : https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume

Comment: you can follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211512/how-to-integrate-swagger-in-lumen-laravel-for-rest-api) works well for me.